# String Comparison Not working Arduino

Tags: string, arduino-uno

Could somebody explain what is wrong with this code. WHY is the if statement always false when it is matching the exact strings..I have tried it with == as well..Still, every time I am getting No Match Found !!.

```
String inData = "";
char inChar;
String property;  
String a = "test";

void loop() {


  Serial.println("String Comparison"); 

  if(Serial.available() > 0){

        while(Serial.available()>0) {
          inChar = Serial.read();
          inData.concat(inChar);
        }

        //Extracting Property
        property = inData.substring(inData.lastIndexOf(":")+2); // Extracts the String "test"
        Serial.println("Property:" +property);


        if(property.equals(a)){ // It never matches though, it is TRUE all the time

           Serial.println(" Matched !! ");

        }      
        else
        Serial.println(" Match Not Found !! ");

       inData = "";


   }

  delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I am able to see matches match and misses miss I think I need more information to replicate the error.

Since I don't see it happening I would guess it has to do with whatever the input is and how this line parses it.

```
property = inData.substring(inData.lastIndexOf(":")+2); // Extracts the String "test"
```

- What is the current input that is failing?
- Can you include your printed output with that input?
- Add a line to print out `property.length()` to test for hidden whitespace characters

Comment: I had this exact problem too, and indeed the string length did not match. I solved it by adding:

`command = command.substring(0,command.length()-1 );`

In your case you can probably fix it by doing +1 instead of +2.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on [this](https://github.com/aeonSolutions/AeonLabs-Home-Automation-Smart-Coffee-MAchine-Addon/blob/main/firmware%20code/telegram.cpp) custom library I've been coding

```cpp
// ****************************************************
bool TELEGRAM_CLASS:: checkMaxDailyCups( String chat_id, String from_name, String what ){
  if ( what == "decaffeinated coffee") || what == "coffee" || what == "cappuccino" ){    
    if( this->coffeeMachine->config.maxCoffeeCupsPerDay == ( this->coffeeMachine->config.numCoffeeCupsToday +1) ){
      this->bot->sendMessage(chat_id, from_name +", i think this will be my last cup of " + what +" today ...", "");  
      this->coffeeMachine->updateNumCoffeeCupsToday();
      return true;   
    }else if ( this->coffeeMachine->config.numCoffeeCupsToday > this->coffeeMachine->config.maxCoffeeCupsPerDay ){
      this->bot->sendMessage(chat_id, from_name + ", I already had too much " + what +" today  ... ", "");  
      this->coffeeMachine->updateNumCoffeeCupsToday(); 
      return false;   
    }
    
    this->coffeeMachine->updateNumCoffeeCupsToday(); 
  }

  if ( what =="tea" ){
    if( this->coffeeMachine->config.maxTeaCupsPerDay ==  (this->coffeeMachine->config.numTeaCupsToday +1) ){
      this->bot->sendMessage(chat_id, from_name +", i think this will be my last cup of " + what +" today ...", "");  
      this->coffeeMachine->updateNumTeaCupsToday();
      return true;   
    }else if ( this->coffeeMachine->config.numTeaCupsToday > this->coffeeMachine->config.maxTeaCupsPerDay  ){
      this->bot->sendMessage(chat_id, from_name + ", I already had too much " + what +" today  ... ", "");  
      this->coffeeMachine->updateNumTeaCupsToday();
      return false;   
    }

    this->coffeeMachine->updateNumTeaCupsToday();

  }

return false; 
}
```

and I was getting incorrect results out of this function. After debugging I found out, spite Arduino reference [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringComparisonOperators) states string comparison can be made using "the operator == and the method equals() to perform identically comparisons".

However, one must keep in mind what happens to a function when the `return` statement is called. And on my particular case (see the code above when `return` is called the `String what` variable returns TRUE on the IF statement below (`if ( what =="tea" )`) where it should not.

Solution: i replaced all `==` string comparisons with `what.equals("xxxx")` and solved the error.